# Mark comment in inbox as read when comment is opened via the link to that comment in an email

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox

If I click on an unread comment in my inbox, the red number decreases (or goes away if the number was one).

This "red number" decrease doesn't happen if I click the link for the comment (the date-time-stamp at the end of the comment), which is also the link that is emailed by SO after a while if you have unread comments. Not even a reload reduces the unread message count, you really need to click the item in the Inbox.

Since the links in the Inbox, for the comment (date-time-stamp) and the email are the same, I assume clicking the Inbox invokes some function through Javascript to decrease the "red number".

It would be great if at least the link in the email would have an extra parameter that has the same side-effect of marking the Inbox item as read (and decreasing the "red number"), even if that would only happen after a reload of the page (or clicking another comment link in the email).

Comment: FWIW, the following API is called when an item is clicked from the inbox: `https://<domain>.com/topbar/mark-inbox-as-read`

Comment: There are many issues with this part of the site, IMX.

Comment: This sounds like a bug to be honest.

Comment: Since this is tagged as a feature request, you may want to edit the title to reflect the request itself (rather than merely describing the current functionality).